# Cannot Declare String In Module VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

I am trying to read database strings from a file for a legacy application. To do this, I place the file in the AppData folder for each user. Now, I need to tell the application where the file is. However, I cant seem to declare a string in a module (the original strings were declared as constants in this module). How can I get over this? any help would be appreciated.

This is what I tried:

```
Dim loc As String
loc = Environ$("APPDATA")
Public Const CnnSTR = ReadIniValue(loc & "\PensionMaster\PM-Strings.ini", "DB", "DBSQL")
```

But I got an **'Invalid outside procedure'** error.

Comment: constants have to be known at compile time; you cannot use (most) functions to define them (e.g. `Environ$`) .  Also that line has to be in a Sub since it is an executable line.

Comment: @Plutonix Ok, thanks for your insights...but how will I be able to pass a value to the variable "loc"?

Comment: If you know what the value of "loc" is before to run, then just add it to the string. But if you want it to be variable, I think it's not a constant what you look for.

Comment: @ Matteo NNZ loc must be a variable. As such, how should I declare it?

Comment: I fear you cannot declare a variable as a constant. The keyword "Constant" stands for "this variable won't change its value anywhere in the code). You might want to re-factor a bit your code.

Comment: Create a Function or Property to return CnnSTR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim Williams is correct. Instead of trying to declare it as a public variable create a public function, or property. My preference is to create a function in a .bas module, and a property in a class.

```
Public Function GetCnnSTR() As String
    Dim loc As String
    Dim strPath as String

    loc = Environ$("APPDATA")
    strPath = ReadIniValue(loc & "\PensionMaster\PM-Strings.ini", "DB", "DBSQL")

    GetCnnSTR = strPath

End Function
```

or

```
Public Property Get CnnSTR() As String
    Dim loc As String
    Dim strPath as String

    loc = Environ$("APPDATA")
    strPath = ReadIniValue(loc & "\PensionMaster\PM-Strings.ini", "DB", "DBSQL")

    CnnSTR = strPath

End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CnnSTR = ReadIniValue(Environ$("APPDATA") & "\PensionMaster\PM-Strings.ini", "DB", "DBSQL"
```

Will work. Maybe a `Dim CnnSTR as String` line as well.

```
Const x=5
y = X
```

is exactly the same as

```
y=5
```